# Excel Visible Cell delete- Broken

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code that uses the autofilter on a datasheet to identify records that have "True" in the first column and deletes the visible rows. My Code was working for months without issue, but today it stopped working and produced an 1004 no records found error. The thing is, I can see the visible rows and if I walk through the code in debug mode it works fine. Its the entirerow.delete line that causes the problem. Can anyone help me figure out what made it stop working?

```
  'Rowzmaster is the count of duplicates
    If RowzMaster <> 0 Then

        'Unfilter All
            If (Sheets("Master Data").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("Master Data").FilterMode) Or Sheets("Master Data").FilterMode Then
                Sheets("Master Data").ShowAllData
            End If

         'Filter
            Sheets("Master Data").Range("$A$1:$B" & lastRowall).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="True"

        'Remove any records that match raw data ( This is where it dies)
            Sheets("Master Data").Range("$A$2:$B" & lastRowall).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way of removing a previous AutoFilter is suspicious to me. Eben though it "worked" in the past but that might depend on versions and other circumstances. also, dont forget that an AutoFilter always considers the first row as a header row, even if it is not the case. So you should not delete the header row after an autofilter. Try rewriting this piece of code this way:

```
    With Sheets("Master Data")
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter
        With .Range("$A$1:$B" & lastRowall)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="True"

            '.offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            '^^^^^^^^^
           ' You can also delete directly, delete acts only on visible cells

            .offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
```